# Expectation of roots of a quadratic equation

Tags: self-study, expected-value, uniform-distribution

The quadratic equation $x^2 -ax+ b = 0$ is 
known to have two real roots, $X_1$ and  $X_2$   $(X_1 > X_2)$ but the coefficient $b$ is a 
positive unknown and can be assumed to 
have a uniform distribution in the 
permissible range of variation. Then what is the expected value of $X_1$.

I found that the roots have terms $a$ and $b$ in it. I took its expectation. But nothing is known about $a$ and it is just mentioned that $b$ follows uniform distribution but range is not specified. So how do l find the expectation.

Comment: @MichaelChernick yes, forgot that part! Also, instead of saying "the roots have terms ...", *write out* the equations (and all your work so far). As for the question, my suggestion would be to take $b\in[b_1,b_2]$, and consider first the $a=0$ case.

Comment: Use the discriminant of the quadratic to find the range of variation for $b$. Now, use the fact that $X_1$ satisfies the quadratic equation and take expectation. Now, you can solve for expected value as a quadratic equation.